# Fetch out positional Indexes where a request pair get matched/occured in a web access session

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

I have this subset of a dataframe

```
lf = structure(list(session_id = c(48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 54L, 
54L, 54L, 54L, 54L, 54L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 74L, 74L, 74L, 
74L, 74L, 78L, 78L, 78L, 78L, 78L, 90L, 90L, 90L), datetime = structure(c(1457050110, 
1457050111, 1457050112, 1457050114, 1457050117, 1457050118, 1457052045, 
1457052048, 1457052050, 1457052051, 1457052052, 1457052054, 1457057067, 
1457057067, 1457057067, 1457057070, 1457057071, 1457058143, 1457058143, 
1457058144, 1457058149, 1457058150, 1457059193, 1457059193, 1457059195, 
1457059198, 1457059199, 1457063485, 1457063486, 1457063486), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), request = c(7, 7, 14, 20, 9, 4, 9, 
1, 12, 20, 6, 12, 4, 15, 8, 8, 12, 10, 6, 6, 13, 1, 5, 6, 20, 
1, 8, 3, 6, 13)), .Names = c("session_id", "datetime", "request"
), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Now i am checking a certain pair of request (req1,req2) is matching or not in given dataframe and if there is a match then fetch the positional indexes where match occurred.

I am using this piece of code :-

```
lf1 = lf %>% group_by(session_id) %>% do(positions = match(c(1,6),.$request))
```

As you see i am taking request pair (1,6) as an instance for demonstration purpose.

Desired Output :-

[image]

If possible i want to filter out those session_ids got NAs . So only session_ids having both match position1 and position2 must not be NA

Comment: Is `subset(lf1, !any(is.na(positions)))` what you need?

Comment: Did you meant `lf %>% group_by(session_id) %>%  filter(all(!is.na(match(c(1,6), request))))`

Comment: as you see by running lf1 code we got positions as list containing where first match got occur .Now from lf1 %>% mutate(position1 = someCodeToFetchPos1,position2 = FetchPos2)

Comment: Or may be `lf1 %>% ungroup %>% filter(map_lgl(positions, ~all(!is.na(.)))) %>% mutate(position1 = map_chr(positions, ~.[1]), position2 = map_chr(positions, ~.[2]))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we need the summarised output from 'lfl', `ungroup` the data, then `filter` out rows with `list` elements having any NA and `mutate` to create 'position1' and 'position2'

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
lf1 %>%
   ungroup %>% 
   filter(map_lgl(positions, ~all(!is.na(.)))) %>%
   mutate(position1 = map_int(positions, ~.[1]), position2 = map_int(positions, ~.[2]))
# A tibble: 3 x 4
#  session_id positions position1 position2
#        <int>    <list>     <int>     <int>
#1         54 <int [2]>         2         5
#2         74 <int [2]>         5         2
#3         78 <int [2]>         4         2
```